# Get password object from Jenkins Credential to push into a batch file which will map a network drive

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, window, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline. Before, I have mapped network drive on slaves by using Jenkins pipeline and Jenkins Credentials `withCredentials()`.

But now, I want to make a batch file which will map the network drive when I execute it.

> How do I get a `credentials object` from `Jenkins Credential` to push
>   it into batch script?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use usernameVariable and passwordVariable in your batch file which you specified in withCredentials definition see example below:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '<CREDENTIAL_ID>',
usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']])
```

WithCredentials will add username and password in environment variables.

Now you can use username in your batch file like `%USERNAME%` and `%PASSWORD%`